# Pattern objects not matching with different languages

Tags: java, regex

I have the following reg expression that works fine when the user's inputs English.
But it always fails when using Portuguese characters.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z]*$");
Matcher matcher = p.matcher(fieldName);

if (!matcher.matches())
{
   ....
}
```

Is there any way to get the pattern object to recognise valid Portuguese characters such as ÁÂÃÀÇÉÊÍÓÔÕÚç....?

Thanks

Comment: Are we to assume that it's also OK to support Russian, Arabic and Chinese names too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want a regular expression that will match the class of all alphabetic letters. Across all the scripts of the world, there's *loads* of those, but luckily we can tell Java 6's RE engine that we're after a letter and it will use the magic of Unicode classes to do the rest. In particular, the `L` class matches all types of letters, upper, lower and “oh, that concept doesn't apply in my language”:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^\\p{L}*$");
// the rest is identical, so won't repeat it...
```

When reading the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), remember that backslashes will need to be doubled up if placed in a Java literal so as to stop the Java compiler from interpreting them as something else. (Also be aware that that RE is not suitable for things like validating the names of people, which is an entirely different and much more difficult problem.)

Answer (score 5):

It should work with `"^\p{IsAlphabetic}*$"`, that takes into account Unicode characters. For reference see the options in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: @MatthewFarwell true, sadly pre-7 Java pattern matching is sorely lacking when working with Unicode.

Comment: Thanks Viruzzo, unfortunately our production servers are all using Java 6 and I'm not sure when they will be upgraded to java 7 :(

Comment: @Thomas: Try `\p{L}` instead, which is listed in the [Java 6 docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Comment: @Donal You're my hero :) Works perfectly......thank you and cheers to everyone else for feedback aslo.

Comment: @DonalFellows post it as an answer so he can award you

Comment: @Viruzzo: If you think so; I really just based it off of what you wrote (and a vague memory that you could match such things though I'd never investigated in depth before).

Answer (score 3):

Check out the [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) doc and particularly the section on Unicode:

> Unicode blocks and categories are written with the \p and \P
>   constructs as in Perl. \p{prop} matches if the input has the property
>   prop, while \P{prop} does not match if the input has that property.
>   Blocks are specified with the prefix In, as in InMongolian. Categories
>   may be specified with the optional prefix Is: Both \p{L} and \p{IsL}
>   denote the category of Unicode letters. Blocks and categories can be
>   used both inside and outside of a character class.

(for Java 1.4.x). I suspect you're interested in identifying Unicode letters and not particularly Portuguese letters?

Comment: That's correct Brian. I've read that document but am not sure how to apply it to my regular expression, is it easily possible with Java 6? Could you provide a simple example if so? Thanks

Comment: http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr18/ - Missed this link in the document, I'll search this for examples and info.